# In discord.py I want to fix ERROR 'Unreachable code'

Tags: discord.py

My code is below.
But after returning, an error of'Unreachable code' occurs in holy.
I want to fix

I am Korean and I used a translator

````
    act = [i for i in acts if isinstance(i, discord.CustomActivity)]
    if act:
        act = act[0]
    else:
        return
    text = str(act.name)
    if text:
        holy = (f'상태메시지 : {text}')
    else:
        return
        holy = ('상태메시지가 없습니다')```
````

Answer (score 0):

In functions, `return` returns a value from the function and stops the function. So any code you write after typing `return` is `unreachable`. That's why you're getting this error. Your question doesn't contain much code, but as far as I can see, you can define the variable `holy` above `return`.